# Problem: BPEL Array population

Tags: soap, soa, jdeveloper, bpel

I created a BPEL process which doing some business logic(lets have fetching data from Department list). and on next activity I have to use the same fetched list.

then I created one xsd for department list and want to add element in that, in this way I will put the fetched list in array and then I can use the same array in next activity(Java embed).

On my first java Embed Activity I have used following code for populating the array.

> for(int i=0; i<10;i++ )
>    {
>     setVariableData("department","/ns1:department/ns1:Dept/ns1['i']:DeptName","value");
>   }

while execution I am getting following exception.

```
<May 9, 2011 6:47:11 PM SGT> <Error> <oracle.soa.bpel.engine> <BEA-000000> <<BPELXExecLet::setVariableData>
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to org.w3c.dom.Element
        at com.collaxa.cube.engine.ext.bpel.v1.nodes.BPELXExecLet.setVariableData(BPELXExecLet.java:750)
```

Will any one please tell me why I am getting error. and is there any alternative way for achieving the goal.

I am using Jdeveloper11.1.1.3.0 and SOA 11.1.1.3.0.

following is my xsd for Department.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252" ?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns="http://www.example.org"
            targetNamespace="http://www.example.org"
            elementFormDefault="qualified">

            <xsd:element name="department" type="DeptCollection">
            </xsd:element>
  <xsd:complexType name="DeptCollection">
    <xsd:sequence >
       <xsd:element name="Dept" type="Dept" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" nillable="true"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="Dept">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="DeptName" type="xsd:string" />
      <xsd:element name="HOD" type="xsd:string" />
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the i in `setVariableData("department","/ns1:department/ns1:Dept/ns1['i']:DeptName","value");` is being expanded as you think. You would have to build up the second parameter as a string first using the value of i, then pass it to setVariableData.

Comment: I have tried this also, it is expecting some Element variable...thanks for response.

Comment: Are you expecting the i from the for loop to be inserted here? It isn't. you would have to do: string s = "/ns1:department/ns1:Dept/ns1['" + i + "']:DeptName" then pass s into setVariableData as second argument.